# putting a span around each character in text

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to put each character of the h1 element in a span.

`console.log(text)` shows each character wrapped in spans `and console.log(string)` shows the correct text. Why aren't the results loading on my page?

```js
var header = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(header);
var heading = document.createElement("h1");
header.appendChild(heading);
heading.setAttribute('class', 'spanify');
var headingText = document.createTextNode("Blah blah");
heading.appendChild(headingText);

var text = document.getElementsByClassName("spanify");
var string = text[0].innerText;
string.split("");
text.innerHTML = "";

for (i = 0; i < string.length; i += 1) {
  text.innerHTML += "<span>" + string[i] + "</span>";
}
```

```css
span {
  background: pink;
}
```

Comment: The two `text.innerHTML` should be `text[0].innerHTML`

Answer (score -1):

The split method returns an array. It does not change the string itself. So your line: `string.split("")` does not do anything. I think you have to do: `var newVar = string.split("")`. Then you have to do the for loop on the array, newVar, not on the string, string.

I tried two versions of your code with these results:

this works:

```
   <script>
    var string = "Blah Blah";
    var newVar = string.split("");
    let result = ""; 
    for(i = 0; i < newVar.length; i+=1) {
        result += "<span>" + string[i] + "</span>"
    }                          
    console.log(result);
```

this does not work:

```
    var string = "Blah Blah";
    string.split("");             
    let result = "";
    for(i = 0; i < string.length; i+=1) {
        string += "<span>" + string[i] + "</span>"
    }                  
    console.log(result)
    </script>
```

I think the problem does involve what I have stated above but I am editing my answer to include a code snippet which addresses some other issues. I used the pipe character instead of span elements because they are visible on the page whereas to see the spans you have to look at the underlying HTML. Hopefully this is useful:

```js
var header = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(header);
var heading = document.createElement("h1");
header.appendChild(heading);
heading.setAttribute('id', 'spanify');
var headingText = document.createTextNode("Blah blah");
heading.appendChild(headingText);

var text = document.querySelector("#spanify");
var string = text.innerText;
var newVar = string.split("");
text.innerHTML = "";

for (i = 0; i < newVar.length; i += 1) {
  text.innerHTML += newVar[i] + "|";
}
heading.innerHTML = text.innerHTML;
```

```css
span {
  background: pink;
}
```

Comment: Your answer should not reference a comment, which is to be considered temporary. Include all information in your answer.

Comment: Your second snippet does not work because you add the text to `string` and not to `result`

Comment: I have assigned the value of string to equal the value of text.innerText and then I make an array from it. Each element of this array is then dealt with in the for loop in a way which is analogous to wrapping it in a span element but actually uses a pipe character. Running the snippet shows that it works. I do not understand why you feel this is not useful to the OP. Please can you explain.

Comment: @user3425506 i am referring to the snippet that is labeled "**this does not work**". It does not work because you do `string += "<span>" + string[i] + "</span>"` instead of `result += "<span>" + string[i] + "</span>"`. The `split` in the OP code indeed does nothing, but it is not the problem, since the string can be accessed with `[]` as well.